# How do we get the coordinates of the shape through xml?

Tags: python

Reading mouse coordinate values was successful. But I need to read the stored coordinate values through the xml.

Value was retrieved using ElementTree.
But once you've put it in an array, the shape of the coordinates is x,y, so the comma in the middle prevents integer conversion. And it's a string, so it's apostrophe on both ends, so you can't convert it.
Please advise me.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<DA>
    <DetectionAreas>2</DetectionAreas>
    <DetectArea>
        <Point>0,0</Point>
        <Point>1280,0</Point>
        <Point>1280,720</Point>
        <Point>0,720</Point>
    </DetectArea>
    <Loitering>
        <Point>625,564</Point>
        <Point>625,0</Point>
        <Point>1280,0</Point>
        <Point>1280,631</Point>
    </Loitering>
</DA>
```

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('./MapFile/C001101.map')
root = tree.getroot()
DetectPoint = root.getchildren()[1]
LoiteringPoint = root.getchildren()[2] 
IntrusionPoint = root.getchildren()[2]
Ipointvalue = []
Lpointvalue = []
Dpointvalue = []


if DetectPoint.tag == 'DetectArea' :
    for DPoint in root.findall("DetectArea/Point") :
        Dpointvalue.append(DPoint.text)
if LoiteringPoint.tag == 'Loitering' :
    for LPoint in root.findall("Loitering/Point") :        
        Lpointvalue.append(LPoint.text)
elif IntrusionPoint.tag == 'Intrusion' :
    for IPoint in root.findall("Intrusion/Point") :
        Ipointvalue.append(IPoint.text) 

ip = len(Ipointvalue)
lp = len(Lpointvalue)
dp = len(Dpointvalue)

for i in range(dp): 
    Dpointvalue[i]
    print(Dpointvalue[i])
for i in range(lp):
    Lpointvalue[i]
    print(Lpointvalue[i])
for i in range(ip):
    Ipointvalue[i]
    print(Ipointvalue[i])   

'
'
'
    def onMouseCallback(self, event, x, y, flags, idx):
        if self.view_state == 'intrusion append' or self.view_state == 'loitering append' or self.view_state == 'counting append':
            if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
                works[idx].area_tmp.append([x, y])
                #print(works[idx].area_tmp)
                #print(Dpointvalue)
```

To create a polyline
The coordinate values I wanted were x and y, but I want to ask for advice because it was recognized like this 'x,y'.

Comment: Do it step by step. Isolate the value inside the tags. Since they are string on first extraction, split them using the comma. This will net you lists of strings. Convert each element of the resulting list into integers. Post-process as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a 'namedtuple' named Point. This object has two int properties x and y. There is a helper method that will help you to translate the data you have (x and y as string) to a Point object

See below

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point','x y')

def make_point(point_str):
    parts = point_str.split(',')
    return Point(int(parts[0]),int(parts[1]))


point_str = '3,4'
point = make_point(point_str)
print(point)
print(point.x)
print(point.y)
```

output

```
Point(x=3, y=4)
3
4
```

Now your code may look like:

```
...
Lpointvalue.append(make_point(LPoint.text))
...
```

Comment: problem has been resolved.
Thank you for your advice. I understood it easily.